# Non-Configurable Bundled Products

Tags: magento-1.9, bundled-product

Good morning all - this is probably a stupid question but I am a newbie.

We sell "packs" made up of predetermined quantities of simple products.

So for example:

```
1 x BESTVALUEPACK might contain
5 x SKU123
5 x SKU321
5 x SKU999
```

There are no options - if you buy 1 x BESTVALUEPACK you get the 15 items listed at a price that may bear no relation to the price of the component items (it is probably cheaper).

How do I set this up?

Magento Community Edition 1.9

Answer (score 2):

Change the option for qty and user-defined quantity and you'll have, essentially, a static bundle product:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. On the 'Price' tab make sure you choose 'Fixed' price and give it your bundle price
2. On the 'Bundle Items' tab click the 'Add New Option' button (you will do this for EACH of your bundle items)
3. Ensure the 'Is Required' value is 'Yes'
4. Click the 'Add Selection' button
5. Click the 'Search' button to bring back complete listing of your products.
6. Check the box in the 6th column and enter 1 in the 'Qty to Add' column
7. Click 'Add Selected Product(s) to Option button
8. Once it has been added, change the 'User Defined Qty' value to 'No'
9. REPEAT 2-7 for EACH of your bundle items
10. Save your changes

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

You can create a bundled product in the Magento admin section as you have specified

- Add a new product
- Use Complex Product Types checkbox is selected.
- Set Product Type to Bundled Product

You can then add you simple products to the bundle and set you price

You can read the full knowledge base section on the [Magento site here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/creating-a-bundled-product)

*From the Magento site*

**Points to Remember**

A Bundle is a “build your own” product type

Bundle Items can be Simple or Virtual products, but without Custom Variants and Options

The Price View of a Bundle can be set to display a price range or “As Low as”

The SKU and Weight of a Bundle product can be set to either “Fixed” or “Dynamic”

Items can have either a preset or user-defined quantity

Items can be shipped together or separately

Bundle product data cannot be imported into your catalog.